# Jquery animated div juddery

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm creating a PHP based site. On the page are several thumbnails contained in a scrolling div. To each side of this there are buttons to scroll the thumbnails right/left. Clicking a thumbnail shows a previously hidden div containing more details for each thumbnail.

My problem is that on selecting the option to close the pop-up the jquery animation becomes extremely juddery. As a novice to Jquery, I'm a bit lost. I've pinned it down to when the following function is executed:

```
  function pilotclosemain(keys) {
  $('#bubbletwo' + keys).hide();
  $('#container-bubble' + keys).hide();
  $('#container-searchxx').hide();
  };
```

The final two divs hidden are litterally just backdrops, and commenting this out doesn't affect performance, so it's only when '#bubbletwo' + keys is hidden. What I don't understand is, while these divs DO contain quite a lot of text-data, the juddering ONLY starts once the pop-up is hidden NOT while it is still visible.

This is the function that closes the pop-up (the html of which is below).

And this is the code I use to animated the sliding thumnails

```
   function slider(direction) {

       if (direction == 1) { 
           $(photowrapper).animate({marginLeft : '-=<?php echo $visibleWidth ?>px'}, 3000);

           } 
       else if (direction == 0) { 

            $(photowrapper).animate({marginLeft : '+=<?php echo $visibleWidth ?>px'}, 3000);

            } 
       }
```

The following HTML is the 'pop-up' div and it's contents

```
<div class="bubble" id="bubbletwo<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>" style="display: none; z-index: 30; left: -50px;">
  <img src="images/transparent.png" width="400" height="620" alt=""/ onClick="pilotclosemain('<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>')"> 
  <img src="images/backgrounds/pilot-window-background-nopic.png" width="1139" height="620" alt=""/>
  <?php }?>

  <div class="bubble-search-backing" id="bubble-search-backing<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>" style="display: inherit; ">
  </div>

  <div class="close-keyboard" id="close-bubble-main<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>" style="display: none; width: 128px; height: 99px;" onClick="pilotclosemain('<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>')">  
  </div>

  <div class="close-keyboard" id="close-bubble-search<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>" style="display: inherit; width: 128px; height: 99px; " onClick="pilotclosesearch('<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>')">
  </div>

    <div class="bubble-top-details" id="bubble-top-details">
      <div class="bubble-name"> <?php echo $row_pilots3['surname']; ?> <?php echo $row_pilots3['firstname']; ?></div>
      <div class="bubble-rank"> <?php echo $row_pilots3['rank']; ?> <?php echo $row_pilots3['rankno']; ?> </div>

      <div class="bubble-squadron"> <?php echo $row_pilots3['squadron']; ?> </div>
      <div class="bubble-country"> <?php echo $row_pilots3['country']; ?> </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="bubble-bio" id="bubble-bio<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>"> <?php echo $row_pilots3['bio']; ?> </div>

    <div class="bubble-bio-overlay" id="bubble-bio-overlay<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>">
      <img src="images/backgrounds/bubble-text-overlay.png" width="981" height="79" alt=""/>
    </div>

    <div class="bubble-bio-overlay-top" id="bubble-bio-overlay-top<?php echo $row_pilots3['key']; ?>">
      <img src="images/backgrounds/bubble-text-overlay-top.png" width="985" height="79" alt=""/>
    </div>

    <?php if ( $row_pilots3['image'] != 'generic.jpg'  ){
?>
    <div class="bubble-photo-portrait" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 0px;">
      <img src="images/photos/<?php echo $row_pilots3['image']; ?>" width="292" height="448" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-photo-portrait">
      <img src="images/bubble-photo-portrait.png" width="320" height="468" alt=""/> 
    </div>
    <?php }  ?>

  </div>
```

Comment: Please reproduce the problem in a small runnable code snippet.

Comment: I would if I could, but the code is rather complicated. A link to the site can be found at http://www.thepcguy.org.uk/wing/